# data type 0xF0 user-defined type has an invalid type specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that has an input variable of datetime
`@ReportDate datetime`
Part of my procedure includes the following call:

```
    SELECT ProviderID, CensusYear, CASE WHEN LEFT(ProviderID, 2) IN ('MD', 'DO') AND w.CountyName=tblAddressContactInfo.PracticeCounty AND SurveySentDate <= @ReportDate THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS PSent,
 CASE WHEN LEFT(ProviderID, 2) IN ('MD', 'DO') AND w.CountyName=tblAddressContactInfo.PracticeCounty AND SurveyReceiptDate <=@ReportDate THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS PReceived
 FROM tblAddressContactInfo JOIN tblCounty w ON w.CountyName=tblAddressContactInfo.PracticeCounty
```

SurveySentDate and SurveyReceiptDate are datetime columns.  I can run the procedure in ssms 2008r2 just fine.
The problem is when I add a tableadapter to the dataset I'm using.  I get this error in visual studio query builder:
[image]

How do I fix this error? I tried changing the variable from datetime to a varchar and then converting later in the procedure but to no avail.  Any ideas?

I am using visual studio ultimate 2010 and SQL Server 2008R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer.  I had to add the @ReportDate variable to the Select statement and reorder some things around.